# Gutenberg Block Variation Picker not working

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to add the BlockVariationPicker like in the WordPress [Github example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/block-variation-picker):

```
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import {
    __experimentalBlockVariationPicker as BlockVariationPicker,
    store as blockEditorStore,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const MyBlockVariationPicker = ( { blockName } ) => {
    const variations = useSelect(
        ( select ) => {
            const { getBlockVariations } = select( blocksStore );
            return getBlockVariations( blockName, 'block' );
        },
        [ blockName ]
    );
    return <BlockVariationPicker variations={ variations } />;
};
```

In my edit function I'm adding:

```
{ MyBlockVariationPicker }
```

The block variation picker does not show.

I have already registered my bloc variations with scope block:

```
registerBlockVariation(
   'my/testimonial',
   [
     {
       name: 'testimonial-1',
       title: 'Testimonial 1',
       scope: ['block'],
       attributes: {
         example: 'testimonial-1'
       },
   },
   {
       name: 'testimonial-2',
       title: 'Testimonial 2',
       scope: ['block'],
       attributes: {
         example: 'testimonial-2'
       },
     }
   ]
 );
```

The block variations should show in `{ MyBlockVariationPicker }` but the don't. Unfortunately there isn't much documentation about this. How can we render the variations of a block using the Block Variation Picker as shown in the Github example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [Columns](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns) and [Query](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/query) block use `__experimentalBlockVariationPicker` and its a really nice component/UI and I agree, it there aren't many examples of how to use it, most likely as its still 'experimental' and still likely to change.

I found that both the Columns and Query blocks display the `BlockVariationPicker` by checking if the current block (by clientId) contains any InnerBlocks; if there are none, the `BlockVariationPicker` is shown. When using this component in your own block, you will need some attribute or property to check whether or not a variation has been selected.

I've put together a basic/working example using the structure of your `my/testimonial` block + variations and based on how the BlockVariationPicker is [implemented in Columns block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/154b34a8f5dff5fec056e0e6941fa3aa141ba823/packages/block-library/src/columns/edit.js#L223):

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import { registerBlockType, registerBlockVariation, store as blocksStore } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { useBlockProps, __experimentalBlockVariationPicker as BlockVariationPicker } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


// Create our own BlockVariationPicker
const MyBlockVariationPicker = ({ name, setAttributes }) => { // Note: We need "name" and "setAttributes" from edit() props
    const { blockType, variations, defaultVariation } = useSelect(
        (select) => {
            const { getBlockVariations, getBlockType, getDefaultBlockVariation } = select(blocksStore);
            return {
                blockType: getBlockType(name),
                defaultVariation: getDefaultBlockVariation(name, 'block'),
                variations: getBlockVariations(name, 'block')
            };
        },
        [name]
    );
    return <BlockVariationPicker
        variations={variations}
        icon={get(blockType, ['icon', 'src'])}
        label={get(blockType, ['title'])}
        onSelect={(nextVariation = defaultVariation) => {
            if (nextVariation.attributes) {
                setAttributes(nextVariation.attributes); // Use setAttributes to set the selected variation attributes
            }
        }}
    />;
};

// Register the Block Variations
registerBlockVariation(
    'my/testimonial',
    [
        {
            name: 'testimonial-1',
            title: 'Testimonial 1',
            icon: 'admin-comments', // Added icon so the variation is visibly different (optional)
            scope: ['block'],
            attributes: {
                example: 'testimonial-1'
            },
            isDefault: true
        },
        {
            name: 'testimonial-2',
            title: 'Testimonial 2',
            icon: 'admin-links',
            scope: ['block'],
            attributes: {
                example: 'testimonial-2'
            },
        }
    ]
);

registerBlockType('my/testimonial', {
    title: 'My Testimonial',
    keywords: ['testimonial'],
    icon: 'admin-post',
    attributes: {
        example: {
            type: "string", // no default set, example is "undefined"
        }
    },
    edit(props) {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

        // If example is undefined, show Variation Picker
        if (attributes.example === undefined) {
            return (
                <MyBlockVariationPicker {...props} />
            );
        }
        // Otherwise show the Editor
        return (<div {...useBlockProps()}><h2>{attributes.example}</h2></div>);
    },
    save: ({ attributes }) => {
        return <div {...useBlockProps.save()}><h2>{attributes.example}</h2></div>;
    }
})
```

If you build the above javascript, the resulting block allows you to pick from the two variations on insertion:
[image: my/testimonial]